# Retry individual chunks with Fine Uploader on checksum mismatch

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

As far as I understand, when uploading a multipart file to S3 you get an ETag in response to completion of each chunk. Is there a way to get those ETags in Fine Uploader and then retry an individual chunk in case of a mismatch?

Thank you!

Comment: I know it's very easy to do with a single-part upload, you just attach a Content-MD5 header to each PUT request and that's it. But that `request.params` option doesn't work with multi-part uploads.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Fine Uploader will retry a failed chunk for you automatically.

Comment: @RayNicholus Does it also verify checksums?

Comment: What checksums, and why would that be the job of the uploader? If you want to be sure that S3 verifies file integrity, use version 4 signature support. But be aware that hashing files client-side comes at a performance price.

Comment: I know that this is not the uploader's job. What I need is verify the checksum (etag) of each chunk of a multipart upload and retry a chunk in case of a mismatch. I know that it has performance costs. That's OK. How do I get a chunk's etag received from Amazon and how do I retry that chunk if a mismatch occurs? I can verify the final etag but in that case I'll have to retry the entire upload again and how do I do that for that matter? Because by default it just re-uploads the last chunk.

Comment: It works fine with a single-part, because I can attach the "Content-MD5" header and Amazon will return an error in case of a mismatch. How do I do that with a multipart upload? Is there any other way than removing the failed checksum upload and re-adding it to Fine Uploader to retry?

Comment: As I mentioned in my last comment, this is built in to version 4 signature support. Just turn that on, be sure your server is providing version 4 signatures, and Fine Uploader takes care of the rest.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use version 4, because boto library doesn't work well with it.

Comment: your best bet is to modify whatever library you are using to support version 4 signatures then. This is support you will need eventually anyway.

Comment: Well, may be I'm not quite right about the boto library, I just know it doesn't work well with Frankfurt bucket. Ok, I'look into it again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But just to make it clear, or in case I won't be able to go for version 4 signature, is it possible to re-upload an individual chunk and get a chunk's etag that Amazon sends in response? May be you can hint at where to look in the Fine Uploader source to get it.

Comment: No, that isn't possible. The entire process would require a good amount of work on your end even if the API did support it, the needed API changes would add complexity to the library.